# How to have choices that change the background of a site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to create some sort of drop-down list or buttons that will change the background of a web page from one jpg or png to another? I will not be using background colors. I don't care whether CSS or Javascript is involved.

I cannot use jQuery as I am not familiar with it or how to appropriately use it.

Comment: Have you try anything? or you have any idea? or you just want someone else to do the job for you?

Comment: I suggest having a dropdown menu where you can select an image and then use jquery and an event handler "`.change()`" to find out when there is a new selection and then change the css 'background-image' to that image also using jquery ie: `$( this ).css( "background-image", "example.png" )`. I am not going to write your code for you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Here in the below example I am using a button to change the background image. You can also use dropdown list to change the background images.

HTML code

```
<button id ="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

jQuery Code

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
});
```

Edited Post with complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">//This link Imports jquery library</script>  

<script>

//This code is responsible for changing the image on button click
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $("#btn").click(function()
        {
            $("body").css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id ="btn">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I implement the jQuery? I'm not too familiar with it unfortunately.

Comment: I have edited the post with all the code. Have a look and let me know if it answers your question or not.

Comment: Also, if you want to learn jquery in depth, then, I suggest you should visit this link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: It does answer my question, thank you very much. Everything works now. The way I thought how to do it was completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use a simple select dropdown with options and set the bg images as a data attribut. then in js you check the select on "change" and set the data attribut (bgimage) as background.